`bmkp-all-tags-jump` logic in bookmark+ library
This bmkp-all-tags-jump function seems to list bookmarks that have all of their tags in the specified set of tags, rather than, what one might expect, all the specified tags being present in the list of bookmarks' tags. It relies on bmkp-all-tags-alist-only. This seems to me as the wrong-way round logic?! Generally, I would never remember all of the tags for each bookmark, but I would want all of the specified tags in a given bookmark.
I understand this is not a proper question. I suppose I can just write a function to reverse the logic.
